# Get specific product attribute and display it in Woocommerce Single Product Pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I have created an attribute called 'dimensions'

I wish to add a snippet that will :-

Display the dimensions attribute (Label and Value) in the single product page under meta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below will display under meta section, the product attribute 'dimensions' label and value in single product pages:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'product_attribute_dimensions', 45 );
function product_attribute_dimensions(){
    global $product;

    $taxonomy = 'pa_dimensions';
    $value = $product->get_attribute( $taxonomy );

    if ( $value ) {
        $label = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;

        echo '<p>' . $label . ': ' . $value . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.

Comment: The value is OK, but the label is not being fetched. Edit: apparently pa_ is important. What does that do?