# Show specific product attributes on single product page (WooCommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I would like to show specific attributes on single product page on WooCommerce.

I'm using [Get specific product attribute and display it in Woocommerce Single Product Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49602770/11987538) answer code

The question is: how i could add more attributes in the existing code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to add more attributes

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'product_attribute_dimensions', 45 );
function product_attribute_dimensions(){
    global $product;

    $taxonomies = array('pa_size','pa_color'); //add your attributes
    //Then we loop each of them
    foreach($taxonomies as $taxonomy){
        $value = $product->get_attribute( $taxonomy );
        if ( $value ) {
            $label = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;
    
            echo '<p>' . $label . ': ' . $value . '</p>';
        }
    }
}
```